# Can I use sleep() in php to stop executing the script while processing a form and updating the mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

let's  say I have  "index.php" . It has a form that POSTS to "signup.php" and then redirects back to "index.php" .It invloes two database queriie ie insertion and deletion . Sp can I just use  sleep for say sleep(2)in "Index.php" to let the queries get completed . I have discovered that I don't even have to leave the page  for doing this ! 
It just refreshes by itself ( bocz of the redirect commane in the processing php file ? ) .

If I have many users using the same file on website at the same time , will this help or backfire ? Thankx!

Comment: It's kind of performance anti-optimization. You should think, if you really want to be programmer.

Comment: I will wager that the downvote has to do with grammar...

Comment: @OZ_: you should think if you want to be useful or just troll around. Anyone beginning their work with any technology is prone to inventing 'solutions' that make experienced users cringe/smile/laugh. We've all been there.

Comment: @Mchl so you understand that sometimes there is a reason to laugh, but you don't think that I can do that? :) You should think about your sence of humour.

Comment: I'm sorry, but saying things like `You should think, if you really want to be programmer.` is not really kind IMHO. That's all I wanted to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to sleep. The database operations will block until they're complete; the script will not continue executing until the database operations are finished.

Forcing your script to sleep for two seconds will backfire terribly, causing every request to sit there doing nothing for two seconds. This will cripple a medium- to high-traffic site.

Comment: @user882440 Did you see ***YOU DO NOT HAVE TO SLEEP***. It will itself sleep the time it needs to process the queries....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a message queuing solution like [dropr](https://github.com/s0enke/dropr/)? With dropr you can catch hundreds of requests per second and your server can work on each one by one. But it's quite advanced. At first you should check your scripts for performance leaks, especially with the database related classes and queries.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the OP asked.